# How to create read-only network share programmatically?

Tags: security, networking, windows-xp

How does one create an administrative network share [1] with read-only permissions from C/C++ or Python under Windows XP?

[1] Necessary in order to access C:\Program Files over the share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create the share with [NetShareAdd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525384%28VS.85%29.aspx).  This will share the directory with a `null` ACL, which is equavalent to allowing everyone full access.  It is not possible to configure permissions with `NetShareAdd` on Windows.

Once the share has been created, get the security descriptor for the share by calling [GetNamedSecurityInfoW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446645%28VS.85%29.aspx) passing in the share name, `SE_LMSHARE` as the `ObjectType`, and `DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` as the `SecurityInfo`.  Once you have the descriptor, use the normal Windows security calls to configure the ACL.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NetShareAdd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525384(VS.85).aspx) for C/C++ (the MSDN includes an example program at the end of the page).

Comment: NetShareAdd() won't let you set permissions. The example uses no permissions.

Comment: The example chooses not to, but you can. Check the info page on the SHARE_INFO_2 structure, there's a permissions member which can be set to ACCESS_READ. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525408(VS.85).aspx

Comment: We tried that. If you look at the documentation for the "shi2_permissions" field it reads "Note that Windows does not support share-level security". Maybe it's possible to do this with  SHARE_INFO_502 instead? Any idea how to create read-only security descriptors for it?

Comment: Check this Experts-Exchange question, in the end the guy was able to make his shared folder read-only using SHARE_INFO_2 and ACCESS_READ (the problem he has is probably different from yours, but in the end ACCESS_READ still seems to work) http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/Q_20148288.html

Comment: (sorry, I guess directly linking to experts-exchange hides the answers... search google for "sharing a folder programmatically" and it's the third/fourth option from the top -- "Programmatically sharing a folder !")