# How can I disable net share folder with C/C++ in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, file-sharing, shared-directory, network-shares

I want to write a program with C/C++ for disabling net share folders and to prevent users from create a new share folder. Does anyone know the methods?

Comment: What's wrong with using the standard Windows tools for doing this?  This is a job for Group Policies, not a C++ application.

Comment: What does it mean to "disable net share folders"?

Comment: @Gabe: My assumption is (s)he is referring to the `net.exe` command with the `share` argument that allows you to create/manage local network shares. But I agree it's a strange way of explaining the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method of doing it [with C++ here.](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=231589)

Here is [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301511/how-to-create-read-only-network-share-programmatically) that addresses a similar issue.

In short, you need to call [GetNamedSecurityInfoW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446645%28VS.85%29.aspx) method with appropriate parameters to get the security descriptor of the folder and then you have to modify the ACL of the folder through [methods explained here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379283%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: First of all, that article is about C#, not C or C++. Second, that doesn't have anything to do with disabling network shares. It's about controlling the access privileges of individual folders.

Comment: Sorry for down vote,it sets it automatic and says vote up requires 15 reputations.it's my first time to using this web,if i get sufficient reputations,i will vote it up.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't think you're the one who downvoted this question. It does indeed require 15 reputation points to vote up *or* down answers, so you couldn't have been the one to vote it down. And it definitely doesn't vote answers down automatically. You've done the right thing by accepting the answer, if you think it's helpful. When you get 15+ points, you can also come back and upvote, if you'd like.

Comment: @Aamir: Despite my criticisms, I was not the downvoter. I get accused of that relatively often, despite my notable tendency not to cast very many downvotes, captured for all to see in my profile stats. I'm sure someone else came along and downvoted before you updated your answer.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I sort of knew that it wasn't you :) That's why I specifically asked.

Comment: Thanks all of you answer my question, but i want to know more about net share.Disable net share folder means user can't share any folders in local computer,even if user want to enable this by modifying group policy or registry.

Comment: @Andrew: There is no way to write a program that disables shared folders that can't be worked around by a user with sufficient permissions. Editing the Registry or the local computer's security settings can always be used to restore the functionality. As I mentioned in a comment, the proper way to solve this problem is setting Group Policies and restricting the rights of specific user accounts. This is not a problem that can be solved by writing a C++ app.

Comment: @Cody Gray:Thanks for your help,I've got what i want,it's really useful.